# Transfer of data from PC to Samsung Note 8 GT N 5100 using USB cable is very very slow

Tags: sync

Transfer of data from PC to Samsung Note 8 GT N 5100 using USB cable is very very slow.Have changed cables as well. Same Issue

Comment: Driver update ?

Answer (score 1):

This is usually caused by plugging the USB cable into a USB 1.0 port on your PC instead of a USB 2.0 or USB-SuperSpeed port. Although they all look the same, and the USB protocol is backwards-compatible, USB 1.0 is much slower, and most PCs tend to have both varieties.

Try plugging the USB cable into a different USB socket on your PC.